# Proving the existence of a certain Lebesgue-measurable set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $ m $ be the Lebesgue measure on $ \mathbb{R} $ and $ f: \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty) $ a Lebesgue-integrable function.

Show that there exists a Lebesgue-measurable set $ E \subseteq [0,\infty) $ such that $ m(E) \neq m({f^{−1}}[E]) $.

I am totally clueless about how to proceed with this. Any help?

Comment: If $ f $ is not required to be in $ {\mathcal{L}^{1}}(\mathbb{R}) $, then
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
n + x & \text{if $ n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} $ and $ x \in [n,n + 1) $}; \\
|n| - x & \text{if $ n \in \mathbb{Z}_{< 0} $ and $ x \in [n,n + 1) $}
\end{cases}
$$
would be a counterexample to the OP’s claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By way of contradiction, assume that an integrable function $ f: \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty) $ exists such that
$$
\mu(E) = \mu(f^{\leftarrow}[E])
$$
for any Lebesgue-measurable subset $ E $ of $ [0,\infty) $. Then
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \quad
\mu({f^{\leftarrow}}[n,n + 1)) = \mu([n,n + 1)) = 1.
$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
       \int_{{f^{\leftarrow}}[1,\infty)} f ~ \mathrm{d}{\mu}
& =    \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
       \int_{{f^{\leftarrow}}[n,n + 1)} f ~ \mathrm{d}{\mu} \\
& \geq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n \cdot \mu({f^{\leftarrow}}[n,n + 1)) \\
& =    \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n \cdot \mu([n,n + 1)) \\
& =    \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n \\
& =    \infty.
\end{align}
This contradicts the hypothesis that $ f \in {\mathcal{L}^{1}}(\mathbb{R}) $.

Comment: can you please explain the inequality step please ? how is it $\geq $

Comment: @learnmore: Hi. Let $ n \in \mathbb{N} $. For each $ x \in {f^{\leftarrow}}[[n,n + 1)] $, we have $ f(x) \in [n,n + 1) $ by the definition of ‘pre-image’. This means that $ f|_{{f^{\leftarrow}}[[n,n + 1)]} \geq n $.

Comment: how should  i interpret the fact that a real valued function is Lebesgue Integrable

Comment: @learnmore: Hi learnmore. Are you asking what it means for a Lebesgue-measurable function $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ to be Lebesgue-integrable? It simply means that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| ~ \mathrm{d}{\mu} < \infty.
$$
The integral is taken to be the limit of a sequence of integrals of simple functions that converge to $ |f| $ pointwise from below. If $ f \geq 0 $ in the first place, then this condition simplifies to
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f ~ \mathrm{d}{\mu} < \infty.
$$

Comment: thanks that was what I am asking